# Cut strokes from other shapes via pathfinder

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pathfinder

Im not that good in illustrator but i followed other people answers here with almost the same problems but didn't help. So i want to cut out the stroke from the other 2 path-s. I already made a Outline stroke effect and the other fonts are shapes too but with pathfinder won't cut as is except because this effect cut the full shape not the stroke and yes only the stroke and that other 2 path is selected...

What make i wrong here ? Thank you for the answers.

[image: I want to cut out the stroke from the other 2 shape via pathfinder but won't work]

Comment: If you expanded the shape with shape and stroke clicked, you should be able to cut resulting stroke shape without problem. Try to show us the end result you want to achieve.

Comment: Hmm almost works i mean the white line cuts the right shape but not the left shape. 



http://i60.tinypic.com/6dxwjl.png

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you just need to place the expanded stroke shape above the object you want to cut from (I give you one way, there are many others) and perform minus front operation selecting both objects.

This is a "part" of your image -

[image]

I expanded the shape, then selected the stroke shape and the right-handed shape and performed minus front -

[image]

The result -

[image]

Comment: Yes, but i can't create this effect with 3 selected shape .

Comment: I think a did it. I just made the same way but for the other shape i used the Exclude effect end deleted the stroke. Its the same i think. Thank for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thanks for helping i finally did it. I needed to select the first 2 shape and add Minus Front effect and for the other shape i made the same way but with Exclude effect and deleted the stroke.